# How to find the source data of a series chart in Excel

Tags: python, excel, charts

I have some pretty strange data i'm working with, as can be seen in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzu8L.jpg). Now I can't seem to find any source data for the numbers these graphs are presenting.

Furthermore if I search for the source it only points to [an empty cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLF7J.jpg) for each graph.

Ideally I want to be able to retrieve the highlighted labels in each case using python, and it seems finding the source is the only way to do this, so if you know of a python module that can do that i'd be happy to use it. Otherwise if you can help me find the source data that would be even perfecter :P

So far i've tried the XLDR module for python as well as manually showing all hidden cells, but neither work.

Here's a link to the file: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx6d-VNCJvgBckw5QkhQd0pVMEE/view)

Comment: I think that second screenshot is after a misclick... no matter how I try to open the "Select data" dialogue on an existing graph I cannot get that top field to populate in that manner. The only way I can get that to populate is to open the select data dialogue and then click on a cell. Did you try to select the data series in the workbook rather than in the "select data" dialogue? the only way to find the _actual_ data range for a series is to select it within the dialogue and click on the "edit" button...

Comment: @Lefty You're right!, i selected the data like you said, and it seems to be an absolute value http://i.imgur.com/qdQjxHq.png. Any suggestions on how I can get that value with python

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing about python :(

Answer (score 0):

EDIT I ended up just converting the xlsx to a pdf using cloudconvert.com API
Then using pdftotext to convert the data to a .txt which just analyses everything including the numbers on the edge of the chart which can then be searched using an algorithm.

If a hopeless internet wanderer comes upon this thread with the same problem, you can PM me for more details :P